# VueJS: Delete multiple tasks. Each task one request?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am rebuilding a TaskApp and I have a "Complete All" Button and a "Clear Completed" Button that deletes all tasks that have been marked completed. The application looks like this:

[image: Vue Todo App]

This is the clearCompleted method.

```
clearCompleted: function () {
    var that = this;

    var toBeClearedTasks = this.tasks.filter(function (task) {
        return task.completed;
    });

    toBeClearedTasks.forEach(function (task) {
        that.$http.delete('/api/tasks/' + task.id, task);
    });

    this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(function (task) {
        return !task.completed;
    });
}
```

As you can see, it has a forEach function that sends a delete http request to my endpoint, for **each single task** that is to be deleted.

That triggers the problem, that whenever I push the yellow **Complete All** button it executes my **completeAll** method, which sends a http request **for each** task to my endpoint.

```
completeAll: function () {
    var that = this;
    this.tasks.forEach(function (task) {
        task.completed = true;
        that.$http.put('/api/tasks/' + task.id, task);
    });
},
```

Now I have the problem, that when I hit the **Complete All** button, and immediately right after it the **Clear Completed** button, the tasks are not deleted, when I refresh the site. But when I give it some time between hitting both buttons, everything works perfectly, indicating, that http request need some time to execute on the serverside.

Is there a way to use something like a queue? Or is there a way to send a single request and then use the foreach loop on serverside? How were you going to solve a problem, where you maybe have hundreds of tasks that you want to delete. Firing for each and single one a delete request through a forEach loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the database indicates whether a task was completed or not, I will be sending a request for `clear` and another request for `complete` tasks.

```
clearCompleted: function () {
  this.$http.put('/api/tasks/clear-completed')

  this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(function (task) {
    return !task.completed
  });
},

completeAll: function () {
  this.$http.put('/api/tasks/complete-all')

  this.tasks.forEach(function (task) {
    task.completed = true
  });
}
```

I hope I was helpful!

Comment: You would solve it by creating more endpoints to the api, and use a forEach loop on the server, correct? Also you probably mean "this.$http.put('/api/..." instead of "this.$http.get('/api/...".

Comment: Yeah exactly! I'll update my answer to use a `put` request.

Comment: I struggled a bit, because I wanted to make the client do the work, but I finally went with your suggestion, because it is indeed really simple. Please one thing to fix: change "this.$http.put('/api/...')" to "this.$http.post('/api/...'). Also then mention using two additional routes:     Route::post('tasks/complete-all', 'TasksController@completeAll');
    Route::post('tasks/clear-completed', 'TasksController@clearCompleted');

Thanks. I still wish I could the frontend do the work, instead of the backend, because I like as few endpoints as possible... but I haven't yet figured that one out.